# cronjob not working - "could not open input file"

Tags: joomla, cron-job

With CiviCRM 4.6.10 and Joomla 3.3.3, I have been unable to get a simple cronjob to process. I just want to run the enabled scheduled jobs every day. In Siteground cPanel, I have setup the following cronjob - 
/usr/local/php53/bin/php-cli /home/ashguild/public_html/home/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=username\&pass=password\&key=key

I am getting "Could not open input file: /home/ashguild/public_html/home/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=username&pass=password&key=key

I don't know what to try next. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This may be something your hosting company can assist you with.  It may well be a permissions problem with how they handle cron jobs.  Also, if your hosting company is still using PHP 5.3, I'd consider using a different hosting company.